# How to fix duplicates import?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

```
import Quasar, * as All from 'quasar'
import { AddressbarColor } from 'quasar'
```

eslint catch duplicates import,
how to call AddressbarColor from those import without duplicating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your function is exported correctly you can get rid of the second Line. For example:

in Quasar.js:

```
export { AdressbarColor };
```

in Index.js

```
import Quasar, * as All from 'quasar';
//to call AdressbarColor use this
All.AdressbarColor();
```

Comment: Ah fool, I do Quasar.AdressbarColor() and got undefined property. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Import `* as All` and assign `AddressbarColor` to a variable using destructuring:

```
import Quasar, * as All from 'quasar'
const { AddressbarColor } = All
```